# How to use *ngIf in *ngFor in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have multiple items in my DocumentModel document, which I all want to show except of 'content'. I already tried to exclude it by checking the name of the item, but it's showing it anyways:

```
<p *ngFor="let item of (document | keyvalue)">
    <b *ngIf="item.key != 'content'">{{item.key}}:</b> {{item.value}}
</p>
```

I also tried using content without '', which is also not working.

How can I make something like `if(!key.equals("content"))` as in Java?

### Document Model

```
export class DocumentModel 
{ 
    messageType: string; 
    content: string; 
    failed: boolean; 
    string1: string; 
    string2: string; 
}
```

Comment: You should filter the array using a getter inside your TS file. That way you don't have to use *ngIf at all inside your template file. The other option would be to use a pipe to filter the array.

Comment: Thank you but this still doesn't explains why the *ngIf isn't working.

Comment: @karottenbunker what is the type of your document?

Comment: @karottenbunker following the example from official angular documentation, following example works. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tndqqz). It would be beneficial if you could share the model of the data, that you are using. Are you sure, that 'content' is present in the data structure?

Comment: That if statement does look good. Are you sure the string is actually `content`? Maybe it has a special character or a space somewhere.

Comment: This is my DocumentModel:

`export class DocumentModel {

  messageType: string;
  content: string;
  failed: boolean;
  string1: string;
  string2: string;
}`

Comment: I have updated the example with model that you have provided, and it is working as expected: (stackblitz)[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tndqqz]. You need to be aware, that it will split your object into prop / value. So only property with name 'content' will not be displayed, the actual value that is assigned in it, will be.

Comment: @RafałCzabaj thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 0):

```
You can create pipe to access key

import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
html:
<span *ngFor="let item of content | keys">           
   <b *ngIf="item.key != 'content'">{{item.key}}:</b> {{item.value}}
</span>
```

Or

Write filter for content data from list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your initial code:

```
<p *ngFor="let item of (document | keyvalue)">
    <b *ngIf="item.key != 'content'">{{item.key}}:</b> {{item.value}}
</p>
```

But if I look at the `*ngFor` it seems that item can be a `document` or a `keyvalue`. So my question is:
Are you sure that `document` and `keyvalue` has the field `key`?

Comment: Hey keyvalue is a pipe. See [this](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/angular-6-1-introduces-new-keyvalue-pipe/)